# Inner function not printing nonlocal variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, closures

I have one `outer function` and `2 inner functions.`

```
def outer():
    x = 'hello'    
    def inner1():
        def inner2():
            nonlocal x
            x = 'python'        
        inner2()
        print(x)
outer()
```

Why is the above code not printing the value of `x`?

As per my understanding, it should print `"hello"`.

Comment: Do you need to close the inner1() loop?

Comment: `inner1` defines and calls `inner2`, but I don't see where `outer` calls `inner1`.

Comment: That's what I meant... boy it's been a long time since I looked at any python code, but I spotted the missing inner1().

Comment: Even if you call `inner1`, `inner2` is going to change the value of `x` defined by `outer`, which is the same value that `print(x)` will print, so you'll see `python` as the output instead. You should see `hello` if, for example, `print(x)` was dedented to be called called in the body of `outer` *and* you neglected to call `inner1`, so that the value of `x` is not changed from `hello`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code calls `outer()`, which in turn executes only one statement:

```
x = 'hello'
```

As it stands, the code in your question will print nothing.

If you were to add the line `print(x)` after the call to `outer()`, it would indeed print `"hello"`, as you have suggested.

If you were to instead add the line `inner1()` to call the function by that name which is defined inside `outer()`, then `inner1()` would in turn call `inner2()` which would in turn cause `x = 'python'` to execute, and this would change the value of `x` and (thanks to the `nonlocal x` line within `inner2()`) the statement `print(x)` within `inner1()` would cause the code to print `"python"`.